# How to drop rows of dataframe with datetime not increasing

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe indexed on datetime, with the following output:

2022-04-08 21:59:49  7651.8  7655.8

2022-04-08 21:59:50  7651.7  7655.7

2022-04-08 21:59:54  7651.7  7655.7

2022-04-08 21:59:55  7651.8  7655.8

2022-04-08 09:47:00  7544.9  7545.9

A valid row has the condition where its datetime value is the same or greater than in previous row (and the first row is always valid).

Therefore, in the extract above, the only invalid row is the last one, as the datetime doesn't meet the above condition.

I have managed to remove the offending row by:

df.drop(df.loc[df.index.to_series().diff() < pd.to_timedelta('0 seconds')].index, inplace=True)

But this looks a little convoluted.  Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.index.to_series().diff() < pd.to_timedelta('0 seconds')` returns a boolean Series, you can use boolean indexing to select rows:

```py
df = df.loc[~(df.index.to_series().diff() < pd.to_timedelta('0 seconds'))]
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply Ynjxsjmh.
Looks more compact than mine - so will use it.  Thank you!